# How to send an HTML email to the user when a button is pressed? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an iOS application, and I need a certain feature so when a user presses a button, an email **that was made in HTML and styled with CSS** is sent.

I already figured out how to send the email when the button is sent, but I do not understand how to use HTML and CSS to make and style the email. I keep trying to type HTML and CSS code into the email body section, but Xcode gives me numerous errors.

Here is my code-

```
 mailComposer.setSubject("25% Human Serum Albumin Calculations for:  \(patientName.text!)")
 mailComposer.setMessageBody(  "<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <body style="background-color: #F2F2F2">
 <p style="font-color:#000000; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;"> Sup Homeslice! </p>
 </body>" , isHTML: true)
```

**What is wrong in my code? How do use HTML to create an e-mail in Swift?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: Swift doesn't have multi-line strings.

Comment: @jtbandes I guess the duplicate I linked was only half of the problem.

Comment: Yes, it did only help half the problem. Can someone please tell me why my CSS still doesn't work after I do the back-slashes and enable the double-quotes inside ""?

Comment: Contrary to your comment, your `body style` and `p style` above have unescaped ". From css point of view I believe it needs to be terminated by semicolon, which is not in the body.